# Nexus disabled creation and updating of scripts

Tags: ansible, nexus, build-automation, ansible-template, nexus3

I've testing on using ansible to automate creation of a nexus server and when trying to deploy groovy, I get the below error. The automation successfully works upto declaring groovy script in the deploy_groovy.yaml file.

```
TASK [nexus : Declaring Groovy script {{ item }}] ****************************************************************************************
failed: [10.0.57.17] (item=update_admin_password) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content_length": "96", "content_type": "application/json", "date": "Fri, 18 Aug 2023 04:54:35 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "item": "update_admin_password", "json": {"name": "update_admin_password", "result": "Creating and updating scripts is disabled"}, "msg": "Status code was 410 and not [204]: HTTP Error 410: Gone", "redirected": false, "server": "Nexus/3.30.1-01 (OSS)", "status": 410, "url": "http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/script", "x_content_type_options": "nosniff"}
failed: [10.0.57.17] (item=create_repo_docker_hosted) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content_length": "100", "content_type": "application/json", "date": "Fri, 18 Aug 2023 04:54:36 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "item": "create_repo_docker_hosted", "json": {"name": "create_repo_docker_hosted", "result": "Creating and updating scripts is disabled"}, "msg": "Status code was 410 and not [204]: HTTP Error 410: Gone", "redirected": false, "server": "Nexus/3.30.1-01 (OSS)", "status": 410, "url": "http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/script", "x_content_type_options": "nosniff"}
failed: [10.0.57.17] (item=create_blobstore) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content_length": "91", "content_type": "application/json", "date": "Fri, 18 Aug 2023 04:54:37 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "item": "create_blobstore", "json": {"name": "create_blobstore", "result": "Creating and updating scripts is disabled"}, "msg": "Status code was 410 and not [204]: HTTP Error 410: Gone", "redirected": false, "server": "Nexus/3.30.1-01 (OSS)", "status": 410, "url": "http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/script", "x_content_type_options": "nosniff"}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************
10.0.57.17                 : ok=26   changed=5    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=1    ignored=0
```

here's my install_nexus.yaml file which runs first

```
---
- name: install dependencies
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: latest
  loop:
    - java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64

- name: Create nexus service user
  user:
    name: "{{ nexus_config.nexus_service_user }}"
    comment: nexus service user
  
- name: ensure app directory is exist
  file:
    path: "{{ nexus_config.application_location }}"
    state: directory
    owner: "{{ nexus_config.nexus_service_user }}"
    group: "{{ nexus_config.nexus_service_user }}"
    mode: '0755'

- name: Download the latest nexus
  get_url:
    url: "{{ nexus_config.nexus_download_url }}nexus-{{ nexus_config.nexus_version }}-unix.tar.gz"
    dest: /tmp/nexus.tar.gz
  register: package_path

- name: get package path
  debug:
    var: package_path.dest
  when: ansible_config.debug == true

- name: unarchive nexus.tar.gz
  unarchive:
    src: "{{ package_path.dest }}"
    dest: /tmp
    remote_src: yes
    list_files: yes
  register: unarchive_path

- name: get path
  debug:
    var: unarchive_path.files[0].split("/")[0]
  when: ansible_config.debug == true

- block:
    - name: remove old config if exist
      file:
        path: "{{ nexus_config.application_location }}/{{ item }}"
        state: absent
      vars:
        fresh_install: true
      loop:
        - nexus
        - sonatype-work
      when: fresh_install == true
    - name: move to "{{nexus_config.application_location}}nexus"
      command: "mv {{ unarchive_path.dest }}/{{ unarchive_path.files[0].split(\"/\")[0] }} {{nexus_config.application_location}}nexus"
  rescue:
    - name: copying files
      copy:
        src: "{{ unarchive_path.dest }}/{{ unarchive_path.files[0].split(\"/\")[0] }}/"
        dest: "{{nexus_config.application_location}}nexus"
        remote_src: true
      copy: 
        src: "nexus.properties"
        dest: "{{nexus_config.application_location}}nexus/etc/nexus.properties"

- name: grant permission to nexus user
  file:
    path: "{{nexus_config.application_location}}nexus"
    owner: "{{ nexus_config.nexus_service_user }}"
    group: "{{ nexus_config.nexus_service_user }}"
    recurse: yes

- name: configuring nexus
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
    line: "{{ item.line }}"
  loop:
    - { path: '{{nexus_config.application_location}}nexus/bin/nexus.rc', regexp: '^#run_as_user=', line: 'run_as_user="nexus"' }
    - { path: '{{nexus_config.application_location}}nexus/bin/nexus.vmoptions', regexp: '^-Xms', line: "-Xms{{ nexus_config.xms }}m" }
    - { path: '{{nexus_config.application_location}}nexus/bin/nexus.vmoptions', regexp: '^-Xmx', line: "-Xmx{{ nexus_config.xmx }}m" }
    - { path: '{{nexus_config.application_location}}nexus/bin/nexus.vmoptions', regexp: '^-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize', line: "-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize={{ nexus_config.max_direct_memory_size }}m" }
    - { path: '{{nexus_config.application_location}}nexus/bin/nexus.vmoptions', regexp: '^-Dkaraf.data', line: "-Dkaraf.data={{ nexus_config.dkaraf_data }}" }

- name: Create a nexus systemd unit file
  template:
    src: nexus.service.j2
    dest: /etc/systemd/system/nexus.service

- name: Add a SELinux policy to allow Systemd to access the nexus binary in path
  command: "chcon -R -t bin_t {{nexus_config.application_location}}nexus/bin/nexus"
  # ignore_errors: Yes

- name: Enable nexus service
  service:
    name: "{{ nexus_config.nexus_service_name }}"
    enabled: yes

- name: Enasure nexus is restarted
  service:
    name: "{{ nexus_config.nexus_service_name }}"
    state: restarted
    daemon_reload: yes

- name: Wait until nexus server get activated
  wait_for:
    port: "{{ nexus_config.default_nexus_port }}"
    delay: 10
```

and here's my deploy_groovy.yaml file which runs next

```
---
- name: enable script creation
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ nexus_config.application_location }}sonatype-work/nexus3/etc/nexus.properties"
    line: "{{ item }}"
    create: true
  loop:
    - nexus.scripts.allowCreation=true
    - application-port={{ nexus_config.default_nexus_port }}

- name: Enasure nexus is restarted
  service:
    name: "{{ nexus_config.nexus_service_name }}"
    state: restarted

- name: Wait until nexus server get activated
  wait_for:
    port: "{{ nexus_config.default_nexus_port }}"
    delay: 2
  
- name: block function
  block:
    - name: get tempory admin password
      command: "cat {{ nexus_config.application_location }}/sonatype-work/nexus3/admin.password"
      register: temp_passwd

    - name: remove tempory password file
      file:
        path: "{{ nexus_config.application_location }}sonatype-work/nexus3/admin.password" 
        state: absent
        force: yes

    - name: Ensure admin password set to default
      set_fact:
        current_nexus_admin_password: "{{ temp_passwd.stdout }}"
      no_log: false
  rescue:
    - name: Ensure admin password set to current password
      set_fact:
        current_nexus_admin_password: "{{ temp_passwd.stdout }}"
      no_log: false

- name: Removing (potential) previously declared Groovy script {{ item }}
  uri:
    url: "http://localhost:{{nexus_config.default_nexus_port}}/service/rest/v1/script/{{ item }}"
    user: 'admin'
    password: "{{ current_nexus_admin_password }}"
    method: DELETE
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 204,404
  loop:
    - update_admin_password
    - create_repo_docker_hosted
    - create_blobstore
    

# - name: Enable Nexus scripting
#   uri:
#     url: "http://localhost:{{ nexus_config.default_nexus_port }}/service/rest/beta/security/scripting"
#     user: 'admin'
#     password: "{{ current_nexus_admin_password }}"
#     method: PUT
#     force_basic_auth: yes
#     status_code: 204
#     body_format: json
#     body:
#       enabled: true
#   register: scripting_result

# - name: Restart Nexus if scripting was enabled
#   service:
#     name: "{{ nexus_config.nexus_service_name }}"
#     state: restarted
#   when: scripting_result.status == 204

- name: Declaring Groovy script {{ item }}
  uri:
    url: "http://localhost:{{nexus_config.default_nexus_port}}/service/rest/v1/script"
    user: 'admin'
    password: "{{ current_nexus_admin_password }}"
    body_format: json
    method: POST
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 204
    body:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      type: 'groovy'
      content: "{{ lookup('file', 'groovy/' + item + '.groovy') }}"
  loop:
    - update_admin_password
    - create_repo_docker_hosted
    - create_blobstore
```

below is the nexus.properties file

```
# Allow script creation
nexus.scripts.allowCreation=true
```